# Is it possible to populate a part of the navigation drawer dynamically?

Tags: java, android

So, I want to populate (part of) my navigation drawer dynamically, based on an array, where each array item has it's own 'button'. Searching on the internet hasn't been able to help me so far, so I could use some help getting this done.

What I want to do, is have a default list, which looks a bit like this:

```
<item android:title="@string/navdrawer_title1">
    <menu>

          //Fill this part dynamically

    </menu>
</item>

<item android:title="@string/navdrawer_title2">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_generalsettings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="@string/navdrawer_generalsettings" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_stuffmanager"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="@string/navdrawer_stuffmanager" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

So, a set part, with a bit that fills dynamically. I guess that filling the entire drawer dynamically isn't that hard, but I have more trouble with filling just a small part of the drawer dynamically. Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely possible to populate the drawer dynamically, I would say this is a very common use case. The drawer is just a container for a view based off screen, it can contain anything. In your case it sounds perfect for a `ListView` with a backing adapter connected to your array.

Good news! The standard guide Google has posted on how to create a navigation drawer shows this exact example. Follow this [guide](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) and adjust it slightly to fit your exact needs.

Comment: The link you provided does not use `ListView` and it does not include any dynamically populated menu items.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to define your custom adapter.

For example:

NavigationItem.java

```
public class NavigationItem {

    public static interface OnItemSelectedListener {
        public void selected();
    }

    private int image;
    private String title;
    private OnItemSelectedListener listener;

    public NavigationItem(int image, String title, OnItemSelectedListener listener) {
        this.image = image;
        this.title = title;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public OnItemSelectedListener getListener() {
        return listener;
    }
}
```

NavigationItemAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.digitalnotebook.R;
import com.digitalnotebook.navigation.NavigationItem;

import java.util.List;

public class NavigationItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<NavigationItem> items;

    public NavigationItemAdapter(Context context, List<NavigationItem> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public NavigationItem getItem(int position) {
        return this.items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View rowView = convertView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            // Create a new view into the list.
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_item, parent, false);
        }

        // Set data into the view.
        ImageView ivItem = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon);
        TextView tvTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);

        NavigationItem item = this.items.get(position);
        tvTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
        ivItem.setImageResource(item.getImage());

        return rowView;
    }

}
```

fragment_navigation_item.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_icon"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="Image Icon"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_icon"
        android:text="Default"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In your activity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
    refreshNavigationBar();
}

protected void refreshNavigationBar() {
            List<NavigationItem> items = new ArrayList<NavigationItem>();
            try {
                for (final Course course : courseManager.getActiveCourses()) {
                    items.add(new NavigationItem(R.drawable.ic_action_go_to_today, course.getName(), new NavigationItem.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void selected() {
                            Intent activity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DigitalNotebookActivity.class);
                            activity.putExtra(Constants.COURSE_ID_PARAM, course.getId().intValue());
                            startActivity(activity);
                        }
                    }));
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                Log.e("HomeActivity", "Error to load active courses.", e);
            }

            mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new NavigationItemAdapter(this, items));
}
```

Refresh method, load the data from the database

This is an example, maybe no compile, I have modified on the fly, but it is a good start.